# How do I include a handlebars template for rendering from backend?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, handlebars.js, commonjs

Is it possible to somehow do something like

```
var template = require("templates/index.handlebars");
```

so that I can include it in a server rendered backbone view.

Answer (score 2):

To read template from the file system use `fs` component:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    template = fs.readFileSync('templates/index.handlebars', {encoding:'utf8'});
```

Comment: Sorry missed that. Do you want to just read it from the file system?

Comment: Yes .. But as far as I know require() can only read js files . In front end I've used text plugin with requirejs for reading template files. Is there something like that for node ?

Comment: Just use template = fs.readFileSync('templates/index.handlebars', {encoding:'utf-8'});